# Magento 1.7 : Set a real time on invoice pdf

Tags: magento, pdf-generation, magento-1.7

i need insert a real time on pdf invoice.
I tried modify app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf files but i no have sucess

Currently only shows day/month, i need show day/month --- hour:minute

sorry my english.